# Self-made ugly vector

Tags: c++, new-operator, undefined-behavior, delete-operator, assignment-operator

I've got some training example of selt-made vector, it's not template for simplicity:

```
class UglyStringsVector {
public:
  UglyStringsVector() = default;
  explicit UglyStringsVector(size_t size);
  UglyStringsVector(const UglyStringsVector&);
  ~UglyStringsVector();

  std::string &operator[](size_t index);

  std::string *begin();
  std::string *end();

  const std::string *begin() const;
  const std::string *end() const;

  size_t Size() const;
  size_t Capacity() const;

  void PushBack(std::string value);
  void operator=(const UglyStringsVector &other);

private:
  std::string *data = nullptr;
  size_t size = 0;
  size_t capacity = 0;

  void ExpandIfNeeded();
};
```

Assignment operator is not implemented correctly:

```
UglyStringsVector& UglyStringsVector::operator=(const UglyStringsVector &other) {
  delete[] data;
  data = new std::string[other.capacity];
  size = other.size;
  capacity = other.capacity;
  copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
  return *this;
}
```

As we see here, when `this == &other` (*I don't check this condition on purpose of question*), it deletes its own memory (*of course this is wrong*), and then reallocates new strings on the same place (`data = new std::string[other.capacity];`), strings are not uninitialized, because default constructor was called during `operator new[]`, and then copy strings to themselves (`copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());`).

Lets imagine than losing memory is not problem :-)
Something whispers to me that copying memory to itself is undefined behavior, but I'm not sure.
The question: ***is there any undefined behavior?***

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: @Bob__ thanks for the answer, but I know about copy-and-swap and know that my code is incorrect at all )) The question is about undefined behavior in synthetic example...

Comment: See [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for tips on the copy/assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `data` is a valid pointer or `nullptr`, then actually there's no UB at all.

With `new std::string[other.capacity]` you create an "array" of [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) `std::string` objects. A default-initialized (default-constructed basically) `std::string` is a valid but empty string.

You then copy this array of empty strings to itself, which is fine.

---

Regarding the self-copying, it's similar to

```
int a = 0;
a = a;
```

which is weird but fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any undefined behavior. You simply delete a memory part which is pointed by the data pointer, and then you re-allocate a new array and assign it to data.